# How to use angular 2 with laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, angular

I am developing a project in laravel 5.4 in which i have to integrate angular2. My laravel project is running now the problem i am facing is that we require to run angular2 using npm through command prompt.

```
npm start
```

But in my laravel project it is not required to run any command in command prompt.
I want to know is it required to run

```
npm start
```

command to start angular2, if i am using it with laravel, if no then how can i integrate angular2 with laravel 5.4.

Here is how i set up angular2 in my project

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart
cd quickstart
npm install
npm start
```

Comment: do you have package.json file in your root folder? Update your post with steps that you followed to set up angular2.

Comment: yes package.json is in root folder of both angular and laravel

Comment: @Aravind please check edit

Comment: what error you get when you run `npm start`

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/toni-rmc/laravel-angular-integration Angular is completely separated from the rest of the Laravel project, watch mode support, TypeScript is separated from the transpiled JavaScript, easy to integrate multiple Angular apps into Laravel, no need to edit anything in the node_modules directory.

Comment: should use angular(frontend) and laravel(backedn) as separate repository

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are going to run you angular app from a NodeJS server, another one that ain't PHP.

So from now on, Laravel will be serving data (JSON) and the angular app will be the one accessed by clients.

But, what you need is just a library to put together your views, components and want to keep serving most of the HTML througth PHP, you should check out some more lightweigth JS libraries like VUEJS or React, as Angular is really a very complete framework and comes with more than what you really need.